# Rails4 - How to add two filters for a single action properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want both the user who created the micropost and the admin to be able to delete the micropost.

I have this in my controller.

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy
.
.
  private

def micropost_params
  params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
end

def correct_user
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
end


# Confirms an admin user.
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

This is in my view where I delete the micropost

```
                <% if current_user.admin? || current_user?(@micropost.user) %>

                  <div class="btn-group" style="float:right">

                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right postdelete" role="menu"  style="color:#383838; background-color: #E6E6E6; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:0">
                      <li role="presentation" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom:0">
                            <%= link_to " Delete ", @micropost, method: :delete,
                                                             data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
                                                             role: 'menuitem', tabindex: -1, :style => "color:#383838" %>
                      </li>

                    </ul>

                  </div>  

                <% end %>
```

I am getting the following error when an admin tries to delete the micropost.

```
2015-05-19T20:23:17.467004+00:00 app[web.2]: Started DELETE "/microposts/142" for 182.65.17.244 at 2015-05-19 20:23:17 +0000
2015-05-19T20:23:17.481204+00:00 app[web.2]:    (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user_languages" WHERE "user_languages"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-05-19T20:23:17.489765+00:00 app[web.2]:   Micropost Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = $1 AND "microposts"."id" = $2  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 142]]
2015-05-19T20:23:17.472886+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by MicropostsController#destroy as HTML
2015-05-19T20:23:17.472897+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"5gLZum2IEbw+WX31H5DR1jGypHNtktiZnYnIclh8i2tY1AxejDYsiDTMIXovEo9EhxkM6xqfJmdRvD40xL/uvQ==", "id"=>"142"}
2015-05-19T20:23:17.476748+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-05-19T20:23:17.484168+00:00 app[web.2]:    (1.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user_learnings" WHERE "user_learnings"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-05-19T20:23:17.490353+00:00 app[web.2]: Redirected to https://www.abc123.com/
2015-05-19T20:23:17.490423+00:00 app[web.2]: Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected
2015-05-19T20:23:17.490552+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)
```

I can see it is due to

```
Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected
```

Can anyone kindly share the mistake I am making? Why isn't the 
admin_user filter not being executed?

How can I enable the admin user also to delete the micropost?

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to delete someone else's post, so the second filter is failing and that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy
```

The above will be treated as an `AND condition` as both of these will be applied in sequence (order depends on the order of declaration). So with that code in place, only an admin_user will be able to delete the records they created - not the ones created by others.

What you are trying could be implemented as a `OR condition` as follows:

```
before_action :can_delete, only: :destroy

....

def can_delete
  correct_user || admin_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'redirecting the user when `@micropost.nil?`, but when you're logged in as *admin*, `@micropost` doesn't belongs to that him, right? It belongs to someone else.

You should do something like this:

```
def correct_user
    unless current_user.admin? 
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

And delete the `admin_user` method, as it won't be necessary anymore.